# My homepage controller action does not recognize User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, forms-authentication

My site uses session cookies, and Forms Authentication. When a user comes in, the menu's check to see if the user is logged in by:

```
Request.IsAuthenticated
```

This works.

I then build that menu item for the users profile in a partial view like this:

```
@model MyApp.Models.LoginStatusModel

@if (Model.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menuItem" data-toggle="dropdown" style="color: red;">@User.Identity.Name <b class="caret"></b></a>
}
else
{
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menuItem" data-toggle="dropdown">Profile <b class="caret"></b></a>
}

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    @if (!Model.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        <li><a href="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/ForgotPassword">Forgot Password</a></li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li><a href="/Trak/List">Trak</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/ChangePassword">Change Password</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/EditProfile">Edit Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Logout">Logout</a></li>
    }
</ul>
```

This works.

And in my homepage controller action (HomeController Index method I have this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            var topGuys = FillTopGuys();
            var upcomingMatches = GetUpcomingMatches();
            var pickemLeaders = GetPickemLeaders();
            var wtGuys = GetTrakGuys();
            var wtSchools = GetTrakSchools();

            return View(new HomeModel
            {
                TopGuys = topGuys,
                UpcomingEvents = upcomingMatches,
                Leaders = pickemLeaders,
                Schools = wtSchools,
                Guys = wtGuys
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorService.LogError(new Exception("Exception occurred trying to load the home page. " + ex.Message, ex));
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

BUT, in the GetTrakGuys method below, the User.Identity.Name is coming back as empty (or null). I can't tell the exact value right now, other than I had the code email me the value and it was blank. (I'm at work, so can't debug via Visual Studio, but still trying to fix it)

```
        private List<WtWrestlerModel> GetTrakGuys()
        {
            var body = "";

            try
            {
                body = "Username: " + User.Identity.Name + Environment.NewLine;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.Identity.Name))
                    return null;

.................
            }
            catch {}
         }
```

Why would User.Identity.Name be blank here, even though the partial view is able to use the value, and other controllers are also using the same User.Identity.Name?

Edit:

I'm not sure if this matters (usually does in that case, right?), but I'm using DevTrends.DonutCaching on the entire HomeController...

Edit2:

Here's how DonutCaching is configured on the HomeController:

```
#if !DEBUG
    [DonutOutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
#endif
    public class HomeController : Controller
```

I deployed this update last night (worked on Dev box, obviously...but no caching there). Even after an hour has elapsed since last night, it still doesn't work.

Oh, maybe it's caching the entire Index method (which would have been for an anonymous user) and since that is cached, and not apart of the "donut" cache, everyone's getting that cached response...

Comment: what kind of authentication you are using??

Comment: Forms, it's in the first line of the question... :)

Comment: the donut caching thing could matter... how is that configured?

Comment: @RobertLevy see Edit2. I'll work on a tweak for the donut caching to see if that fixes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For donut caching to work, you need to define "donut holes" which are separate MVC actions that don't get cached.  Here's the example in the docs:

> If you run your application at this stage, the DonutOutputCache will
>   just act in the same way as the built-in OutputCache and cache the
>   full page. In order to start donut caching, we need to introduce a
>   donut hole. Remember that we have implemented this by adding several
>   overloads to the Action HTML helper. In all overloads, we just need to
>   add a final true parameter to the call indicating that we do not want
>   it cached with the parent page.
>
> `@Html.Action("Login", "Account", true)`
>
> Run the application again and
>   you will see the donut caching in action. Whilst the parent page will
>   be cached for whatever duration you specified, the donut hole action
>   will be executed every request.

http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm working on right now. I've already got that impelmented for that menu item partial view that I posted in the question. Was working on doing the same thing for this. Now I'm running into the issue of trying to update my code directly from BitBucket...got a merge error and I'm struggling trying to get that resolved right now (my LoginStatus code is using @Html.Action(......))

Comment: FYI - I started getting my debugging emails with the username...so this was definitely the fix. Now if I just remember to add my view to the csproj before deploying...sucks trying to make code changes straight from bitbucket while at work and can't test...

Comment: Quick question Robert, since the @Html.Action is getting called from a page/view that is cached, and the partial view that is returned is for a specific user, how could I cache that when no parameter is passed (so have a cached result for every user)? If I try to send the parameter from @Html.Action("action", "controller", true, new { username = User.Identity.Name }) wouldn't that be pulling the cached value (which in my example was anonymous)?

Comment: if you pass 'true' it won't use cache for that bit.  if you want it to sometimes cache, use a different action